# How to get thread id using ZwQuerySystemInformation() in kernel mode?

Tags: c, windows, kernel

I use `ZwQuerySystemInformation()` to enum all processes, and can get all info about each process, also I am able to get `SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION`.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION
{
    LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreateTime;
    DWORD WaitTime;
    PVOID StartAddress;
    CLIENT_ID ClientId;
    KPRIORITY Priority;
    LONG BasePriority;
    DWORD ContextSwitches;
    DWORD ThreadState;
    DWORD WaitReason;
} SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION;
```

But this structure doesn't contain thread id, why ? How can I get this id ?

One more question:I get `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure, it contains pointer to all threads within the process: `SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION Threads[1];` But how do I know **how many** threads in this process ?

PS: I work in kernel mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, If you look carefully **CLIENT_ID** member of the **SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION**, it contains thread ID.

Do you see second member of the **SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION** ?

If yes, is named **NumberOfThreads**, so you may guess what the mean, hooray -> number of threads -> number of **SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION** structs.

Comment: thank you ! maybe you know how to get full path(I can get only name) and company name of a process from `_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure ?

Comment: ZwQueryInformationProces with ProcessImageFileName. Company name is stored in resource section of the executable, this have nothing with SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION.